# Double type in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have two questions regarding precision in MATLAB

1) Is double the data type with the most large number of digits for a float complex number?

2) How can the precision of integral() be augmented? It seems to me that there is a cap at around E+15 (for a large number)

Comment: For precision that is larger than what your machine supports in hardware, you can try using the `symbolic` toolbox with the `vpa` (variable precision arithmetic) function. Or you can try some of the `precision` toolkits in matlab fileexchange.

Comment: Alright, but how  can an integral be computed to E-20 accuracy, for example? (with vpa I guess)

Comment: I should also point out that since you can use Java classes from within matlab / octave directly, another option is to just piggy-back on existing arbitrary precision facilities present in Java.

Comment: @Peter Please don't ask the same question multiple times. If you're not getting the answers you want, clarify your question. Or maybe just be a little more patient. I've voted to close your other two questions as duplicates of this one.

Comment: Only one of them was related to the precision. If you want to close the other one, feel free, but the answer was really good, and I think other people would benefit!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example script comparing `double` to `symbolic/vpa` precision:

```matlab
% Numeric approach
f_numeric = @(z) exp(z.^2);
Out_numeric = integral (f_numeric, 0, 1);

% Symbolic / vpa approach
syms x
f_symbolic(x) = exp(x^2);
Out_symbolic = int (f_symbolic, x, [0,1]);

% Comparison
fprintf('Numeric  : %0.30f\n', Out_numeric)
fprintf('Symbolic : %s\n'    , char   (vpa (Out_symbolic, 32)))
fprintf('Converted: %0.30f\n', double (vpa (Out_symbolic, 32))) % back to double
```

Output on my machine (eps = 2.2204e-16):

```matlab
Numeric  : 1.462651745907181499717353290180
Symbolic : 1.462651745907181608804048586857
Converted: 1.462651745907181499717353290180
```

More generally:

```matlab
>> fprintf(' %0.32f\n %s\n', 1/3, char (vpa ('1/3', 32)))
 0.33333333333333331482961625624739
 0.33333333333333333333333333333333
```